# Problems with createdb in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, role

I have to run a simulation with several postgresql databases spread on different machines which all of them are running linux.

I successfully compiled and built postgresql from the source code and I can also run the server, but when I try to create a new db with this command:

```
./postgresql/bin/createdb db1
```

I get this error:

```
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "giulio" does not exist
```

where giulio is my username to access all the machines.

On some machine it works while on other it does not. I really cannot figure out the root of the problem. I suppose it is something related with the access control of postgres.

I did several research on google but I was not able to found and to solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to get this work?

Thanks,

-Giulio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that on the machines where the user "giulio" is already known, you executed `initdb` with exactly this user making him the DB superuser. A quote from `inidb(1)` (emphasis mine):

> --username=username
>                 Selects the user name of the database superuser.  **This  defaults
>                 to  the  name of the effective user running initdb.** It is really
>                 not important what the superuser's name is, but one might choose
>                 to  keep the customary name **postgres**, even if the operating sys‐
>                 tem user's name is different.

On the other machines I assume you did execute `initdb` with another user, hopefully using `postgres`.

In order to get back on the standard track I propose, that you delete the database cluster on the machines where "giulio" is the superuser and setup a new database cluster using the standard `postgres` user. Then add another user "giulio". This will avoid more confusion down the road as some scripts/programs expect a superuser account named `postgres`.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL has its own users and roles that are separate from that of your OS. Generally there is a dedicated super user, postgres. For user management info, look here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/user-manag.html

When executing postgres commands, you need to specify the user with the -U flag (unless you are already logged in as an existing db user). When you called the createdb script, because you didn't use the -U flag, the server assumed that the uid of the caller (giulo) should be used, but you didn't add a user "giulio" to the db, and hence the error message.

So execute the command as

`./postgresql/bin/createdb -U postgres db1`

and it should work. Then, later on, you may want to create other users and roles in your db rather than doing everything as the superuser.

Answer (score 1):

My answer was more simple...I realized I needed to just run the following:

```
brew install postgresql
```

then to check if it worked I ran:

```
which createdb
```

to check the file path and if it worked, and it had ! Hope this helps.