# Postgres createdb: command not found Mac OS Terminal

Tags: macos, postgresql

After `su postgres` and typing of my password in my macOS terminal, it shows `bash-3.2$`

What when I type command like `createdb`, it says:

> bash: createdb: command not found

I googled and it says "either PostgreSQL was not installed at all or your shell's search path was not set to include it."

How can I fix this?

Comment: The duplicate answer has been removed so should the duplicate flag be removed?

Comment: The answer below didn't help me but I did find the answer "brew install postgresql" here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22285440/908677

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140530110851/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261005/install-postgresql-in-mac-os

Answer (score 1):

Before typing in `su postgres` type in `which createdb` which will tell you what the path is for createdb.  For example if which returns `/usr/local/bin/createdb`, you would add that path to your environmental variable `$PATH` by typing  `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` in the command line once you type `su postgres`.  Then you can run createdb.

Alternatively, you can just specify the full path in the command line `/usr/local/bin/createdb`.  If you need to do this often, you can add the line to change the `PATH` variable in `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Thx for the help but it says "createdb not found" after I typed "which createdb"

Comment: @user3315620 Have you installed postgres?  How did you do it, and where was it installed?

Comment: I downloaded it from the website and put it(PostgreSQL 9.3) in /Applications

Comment: The PostgreSQL 9.3 file consists of Application Stack Builder, Documentation, pgAdmin III, Reload Configuration, SQL shell(psql)

Comment: Try  (you should install homebrew first):```brew install postgresql```

Comment: I also had this sam headache when installing postgres from the official installer. DONT USE IT.